# Primefaces dataTable doesn't refresh the content

Tags: datatable, primefaces, loading, lazy-evaluation

I have some problems with refreshing on a lazy loaded dataTable of Primesfaces. I'm using 3.0.M4.

Have three classes like in your example with the filter. Tried also the example with lazy loading only but then the data wasn't reloaded in the controller. So I've used the second example with filtering. There I get reload events in the controller (logger displays "Loading data").
But the table doesn't show the new data :-(. Why?

Anybody who can help here?

Kind regards!

LazyCarDataModel

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.helloworld;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SortOrder;

/**
 * Dummy implementation of LazyDataModel that uses a list to mimic a real datasource like a database.
 */
public class LazyCarDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Car> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Car> datasource;

    public LazyCarDataModel(List<Car> datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {
        for(Car car : datasource) {
            if(car.getModel().equals(rowKey))
                return car;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Car car) {
        return car.getModel();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
        List<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();

        //filter
        for(Car car : datasource) {
            boolean match = true;

            for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                try {
                    String filterProperty = it.next();
                    String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                    String fieldValue = String.valueOf(car.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(car));

                    if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue)) {
                        match = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    match = false;
                } 
            }

            if(match) {
                data.add(car);
            }
        }

        //sort
        if(sortField != null) {
            Collections.sort(data, new LazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
        }

        //rowCount
        int dataSize = data.size();
        this.setRowCount(dataSize);

        //paginate
        if(dataSize > pageSize) {
            try {
                return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
            }
        }
        else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

LazyTableBean

```
package org.jboss.as.quickstarts.helloworld;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LazyTableBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LazyTableBean.class);

    private final static String[] colors;

    private final static String[] manufacturers;

    private List<Car> cars;

    static {
            colors = new String[10];
            colors[0] = "Black";
            colors[1] = "White";
            colors[2] = "Green";
            colors[3] = "Red";
            colors[4] = "Blue";
            colors[5] = "Orange";
            colors[6] = "Silver";
            colors[7] = "Yellow";
            colors[8] = "Brown";
            colors[9] = "Maroon";

            manufacturers = new String[10];
            manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";
            manufacturers[1] = "BMW";
            manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";
            manufacturers[3] = "Audi";
            manufacturers[4] = "Renault";
            manufacturers[5] = "Opel";
            manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";
            manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";
            manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";
            manufacturers[9] = "Ford";
    }

    private LazyCarDataModel lazyModel;

    private Car selectedCar;

    public LazyTableBean() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

        populateLazyRandomCars(cars, 100000);  
        lazyModel = new LazyCarDataModel(cars);  

    }

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

    public LazyDataModel<Car> getLazyModel() {
        return lazyModel;
    }

    private void populateLazyRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {
        System.out.println("Loading data");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
            list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));
        }
    }

    private String getRandomColor() {
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private String getRandomManufacturer() {
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];
    }

    private int getRandomYear() {
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);
    }

    private String getRandomModel() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);
    }

}
```

And here the xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="template-default.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="content">

    <h:form>

      <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{lazyTableBean.lazyModel}"
        paginator="true" rows="10" lazy="true"
        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
        selection="#{lazyTableBean.selectedCar}" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
          listener="#{lazyTableBean.onRowSelect}" update=":form:display"
          oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />

        <p:column headerText="Model">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Color">
          <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>

      <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog"
        resizable="false" width="200" showEffect="explode"
        hideEffect="explode">

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

          <f:facet name="header">
            <p:graphicImage
              value="/images/cars/#{lazyTableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}.jpg" />
          </f:facet>

          <h:outputText value="Model:" />
          <h:outputText value="#{lazyTableBean.selectedCar.model}" />

          <h:outputText value="Year:" />
          <h:outputText value="#{lazyTableBean.selectedCar.year}" />

          <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />
          <h:outputText
            value="#{lazyTableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}" />

          <h:outputText value="Color:" />
          <h:outputText value="#{lazyTableBean.selectedCar.color}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
      </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I have it. Thank you for your ideas! This brought me on another idea. Even the exmaples doesn't have an id attribute on the p:dataTable tag, I set this now and the table works as expected.
So a

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="car"...
```

helped ;-).

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:**
1. Give your `<h:form>` an id. (`<h:form id="tableForm">`)
2. Change the update attribute from `<p:ajax>` to (`update=":tableForm"`) without :display

**If this isn't working. Try this:**
1. Change `@Named` Annotation to `@ManagedBean`
2. Change `@SessionScoped` to use *`javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`*

This are just some ideas. Try it :)